# UIPageViewController: Page stacks on top of the other

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have built a `UIPageViewController` which has a `UITableView` on it.

When I scroll to the second page and then back to the first, the second top is covering a bit of the first page.

Illustration: [linked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaoVM.jpg)
You'll see 3 images: First page before, first page after and the view debugger showing one view stacked on top of the other.

Do you have any ideas on why this could happen and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the pictures you posted, I seems that your pages have a wrong width. They are wider than your screen size. It might be your issue.
Rework your views so they have the same width as your screen and everything should run smoothly.

Comment: Well, that was.. obvious. I had some wrong constraints in the table view. Thanks!